# taking out only arithmetic operator in variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

value is -1
I want to take out - sign in a variable how can I do this

Comment: Look into the `abs()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: abs() will remove the - operator.i required only - operator in a separate variable

Comment: @AliHassan - What I understood from your question is that you are interested in the sign only.. and not the number. If I am right then see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the "-" (minus) sign in a separate variable, you need to use the `substr()` function.

```
<?php
    echo substr('-1', 0, 1); // will result in "-"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

These sql useful to you.

```
select replace(column_name,'-','') from table_name
```

Eg:- `select replace(-1,'-','')`

Thank you.